# How to extend the 1-d z-transform, describing a function on the unit circle, to two dimensions to describe a function on the unit sphere?

Tags: probability, functions, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, spheres

I'm an electrical engineer with a background in digital signal processing. I know the one-dimensional Z-transform as a tool to describe discrete-time signals/sequences. For instance, if a discrete-time sequence $h(k), k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is given, its Z-transform is given by
$$
H(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h(k) z^{-k}.
$$
Neatly, the discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT) can be found by substituting $z = e^{j \omega}$. I recently found that a Z-transform (and Laplace transform for the continuous case) can be defined as an expected value, but I have not understood this completely yet. Frequently, Z-transforms are represented by a rational function
$$
H(z) = \frac{ A(z) }{B(z)} = H_0 \frac{ \prod_i \left( z - z_{0,i} \right) }{\prod_j \left( z - z_{\infty,j} \right)},
$$
where $z_{0,i}$ describe the zeros and $z_{\infty,j}$ describe the poles.

If I wanted to describe a complex-valued function on the unit circle, $g: \mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, I could perfectly describe it via the zeros and poles of a Z-transform.

Now I would like to extend this concept in order to describe a function on the unit sphere, $f: \mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, instead of on the unit circle. I have complex-valued data (measurements of the function) on a very dense grid on the sphere, where each point is specified by two angles, e.g., azimuth and elevation. My question is if there is a higher-dimensional version of the Z-transform which I could use for this purpose. Or how could I define it? I would like to obtain a representation using poles and zeros again because that seems to be suitable for my application. I suspect that the poles and zero would then lie inside or outside the unit sphere.

2-D Z-transforms are used in image processing. However, the two dimensions are separable for rectangular images. I don't that would be the case for the two-dimensional extension of the Z-transform I look for here because the dimensions on the sphere are not separable but "interconnected".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "If I wanted to describe a complex-valued function on the unit circle, I could perfectly describe it via the zeros and poles of a Z-transform' — this isn't strictly true; it's only true up to (a multiplicative factor of) a nonzero _entire function_. That is largely irrelevant for signal-processing purposes, but that speaks to one aspect of this (otherwise interesting) question that I think it would help to expand on: what aspects of describing a function you're interested in.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I agree on the multiplicative factor, and I edited the post accordingly. I want to model data on the sphere by a parametric representation including the multiplicative factor and the poles/zeros. That's what I mean by describing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose you could start with this formulation:

$$H(z, w) = \sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty h[k,l] z^{-k} w^{-l}$$

With the following substitutions for the unit sphere:

$$ z=e^{j\omega}$$
$$ w = e^{j\xi} \text{ or } w= e^{j\xi/2}$$

How were you actually going to specify the function on the unit sphere?  I assume you need a function of 2 angles unless you have a high degree of symmetry.